# Why in range for loop do begin/end need to be copyable?

Tags: c++

When looking at what range-based for loops actually do here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for#Explanation, I see that the `begin_expr` and `end_expr` are taken by value, i.e. using copy constructor:

```
auto __begin = begin_expr ;
auto __end = end_expr ;
```

Is there a reason the begin/end are taken like that, or is it an oversight? Wouldn't it be better to either `move` them:

```
auto __begin = std::move(begin_expr) ;
auto __end = std::move(end_expr) ;
```

or to take them by forwarding ref:

```
auto && __begin = begin_expr ;
auto && __end = end_expr ;
```

Comment: I'm struggling to imagine what an iterator implementation does that gives it a valid reason not to be copyable.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it is an `InputIterator` over the results of an sql query. If there were copies of it, incrementing one would change the others, and when it goes out of scope it attempts to close the query

Comment: Look also at what is `begin_expr`/`end_expr` basically `begin(__range)`, and `std::move` in `std::move(begin(__range))` is at best unneeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a reason the begin/end are taken like that, or is it an oversight? Wouldn't it be better to either move them:

In general no, because such specification could potentially prohibit copy elision.

> Why in range for loop do begin/end need to be copyable?

The initialisation that you quote doesn't generally necessitate the iterators to be copyable, except in an unusual case where `begin` / `end` return an lvalue reference. I'm not sure if anyone cares about such case, given that would violate concept requirements.

Comment: That is my case. What requirements is it violating?

Comment: @Baruch If it's a container, then it violates the concept of container whose begin/end must return iterator/const_iterator (rather than an lvalue reference to such).

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a user-defined type, the expectation is those expressions are prvalues.

It will either be `__range.begin()` or (adl) `begin(__range)`, which are both function calls. If that is returned by value, there is no object to copy, as it is an unmaterialised temporary at that point, thus there is no point in `std::move`ing it. If that is returned by reference, `std::move`ing it will mutate `__range` to move-initialise `__begin`, which is a surprising behaviour.

In the case of an array, *begin-expr* is a lvalue, but that is trivial to copy. *end-expr* is a prvalue already.